# Kicked out to login screen when order is placed from within admin

Tags: php, magento, ssl, payment-processing

i have an issue where i place an order through the Magento admin , and right when i put in the CC information and click “Submit Order”, i get kicked out to the Magento login screen.  Once i log back in, im able to see that the order was submitted successfully. It does this for every order in the Admin, orders through the frontend work just fine.

Magento 1.4.2

Modules:

- AW_CatalogPermisisons
- Jira_magebridge
- RicoNeitzel_PaymentFilter

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out it was a Magento / Magebridge configuration issue.  Despite following the Magebridge guide for configuring the secure and unsecure urls to the T, i needed to set general > web > secure to use default,in the "Main Website" configuration scope(not the default config scope).  The guide said it should be set to the joomla site path.  When an order was placed from within the Magento admin it would use the joomla base url once the order was submitted, not the magento base url.

I'll go raise some hell at the Yireo forums about this now.